# Changing Format in XLSX file created using XlsxWriter module

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to change the format in an excel file that has been created using the XlsxWriter module in Python, but so far I haven´t been able to do it. Whenever I open the file in Excel and try to change the border formats nothing happens.

The code I´m using is doing what it is supposed to:

```
#Test Sheet
    
    #Format
    _format = workbook.add_format({'top':True, 'bottom': True, 'right': True, 'left': True})
    
    _era.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test', header=False, index=False, startcol = 2, startrow = 2)
    
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Test']
    worksheet.hide_gridlines(2)
    worksheet.conditional_format(2, 2, 20, 11, {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': _format})
```

The Output:

[image]

But afterwards, when I try to change the cell borders format in Excel, nothing happens, it stays the same:

[image]

[image]

And the result is the exact same thing I downloaded in the first place:
[image]

I've tried lots of things, but I must be missing something regarding the code I´m using, is there somebody willing to help?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the data grid is being formatted with a conditional format and that overrides any manual border format that is later applied to the cells.

This isn't related to XlsxWriter. It would also happen with a file created in Excel.